# Shopify variable price for a single product

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am about to display a rack builder in my shopify.

The users can set various customization like the number of rows and columns and the size of each cell and its door option for each cell.

The problem is that I would like to know how to enable variable price for that product. I think I cant use variant product as it will be limited in number.

Answer (score 0):

This will require quite a lot of customisation.

First you will need to split your rack elements into separate products:

- doors
- rows
- columns
- sizes

You will need to enter variants for each of the different elements.

Once you are done with that you will need to create a page that allows you to customise the product showing the options from the product elements you created above.

You will need to collect the product customisation with JS and add the appropriate amount of each element to the cart.

In case the customer have the option of manual input and the price is changed based on that ( for example the size of the wood ) then the functionality will become even more complex.

Long story short it will be hard to code, the administration will be complex and the user experience won't be nice.

Another way will be to look into some APP that can help you with this, but I'm not sure if there is one that has this kind of functionality.